# Among Lucene/Solr, Whoosh, Sphinx, Xapian which integrates best with python?

Tags: python, solr, full-text-search, sphinx, whoosh

I am a newb coder in a startup and I am implementing search of documents in a directory in a web host.

I am comparing Lucene/Solr, Whoosh, Sphinx and Xapian. Whoosh is natively python. But I want your opinions on it too. Which of these have

- mature and easy to use and install interfaces with python? (Whoosh is a no-brainer)
- no chance for crashes, bottlenecks and other failures
- best documented interface (Im not reading PHP docs because python docs were sparse)
- easiest to get up and running (only one has a quick-start tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking for Apache Solr, Python has [several Solr clients](https://websolr.com/guides/solr-clients), which I've collected based on feedback from our customers at [Websolr](http://websolr.com/):

1. [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) is very popular, and designed for seamless integration within Django apps. If you're developing a Django app, Haystack is for you.
2. [Sunburnt](https://github.com/tow/sunburnt) looks to be more generic than Haystack, and is also very well documented. If you're doing plain ol' Python, Sunburnt is worth a look.

Other Python Solr clients that I've found, which seem a bit lower level...

- [solrpy](http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/)
- [pysolr](https://github.com/toastdriven/pysolr) (I know, right?)
- [Insol](https://github.com/mdomans/insol)

Some more details about how your app is built (in particular, is it a Django app?) would help narrow things down from here. Good luck finding the best fit for your app!

Comment: I decided to do it the generic XML/HTTP way. Its not a DJango app. Its a backend task which would have been too tedious to do in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Use Whoosh if you don't need the speed, extra features of the alternatives. It's great, has a nice API, good documentation. My second choice would probably be Xapian, which is fast and has a fairly decent API. They are all fairly mature products. If you don't know what you really need, I'd just go with Whoosh for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want quick python integration, try [indextank](http://indextank.com/documentation/tutorial-python). You can be up and running in 2 minutes, and it's free.

For the other alternatives, I'd go with Solr (provided you want to host the search servers yourself, or signup for [websolr](http://websolr.com) )

Disclaimer: I work at indextank.

Comment: IndexTank is now open source: http://engineering.linkedin.com/open-source/indextank-now-open-source